# Raspberry auto reconnect with another IP

Tags: raspbian, networking, pi-2, static-ip

I configured the file /etc/network/interfaces with this as follows:

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.111
gateway 192.168.1.254
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4 8.8.4.4
```

and I disabled the service called : dhcpcd.
If I disconnect the ethernet cable and wait a few minutes, the Raspberry goes online with another IP : 192.168.1.86.
Why is this happening? I don't have any idea.

Comment: You probably haven't disabled `dhcpcd`; your settings look improbable, to say the least. You don't say which OS, but you may not even have `eth0` Even though I think static IP addresses are a bad idea, if you REALLY must set up see [How to set up Static IP Address](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/74428/8697)